# Jboss 6.1.0 application is already installed

Tags: java-ee-6, jboss6.x, ejb-2.x

I am trying to migrate an application from JBoss 4.0.5 to JBoss 6.1.0. I use ant for deployment. This is my application.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd"
    version="6">
        <application-name>Fantana</application-name>
        <module>
            <ejb>fantana.jar</ejb>
        </module>
        <module>
            <web>
                <web-uri>fantantaWeb.war</web-uri>
                <context-root>/</context-root>
            </web>
        </module>
        <module>
            <web>
                <web-uri>fantanaTerm.war</web-uri>
                <context-root>/</context-root>
            </web>
        </module>
    </application>
```

When I deploy I have the following files generated in the "deploy" folder of the server.

```
fantana.jar
fantana.war
fantanaWeb.war
fantanaTerm.war
```

When runnning the server I get the following issue:

```
15:34:29,296 WARN  [Digester] Empty stack (returning null)
15:34:29,319 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/crud
15:34:29,364 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfs:///D:/abujdei/develop/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/brendolan/deploy/fantana.war state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error deploying: jboss.naming:application=fantana
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: jboss.naming:application=fantana is already installed.
```

I know this issue has been adressed before but I am unable to understand why this happends.
If necessary I can provide more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@ionutab

So ok. I have renamed the file

```
fantana.war
```

into

```
fantanaCore.war
```

I have read in several posts over the internet that somehow necause fantana.jar and fantana.war have the same name it is not ok.
I have renamed it in the ant task, not in the filesystem. (VERY IMPORTANT)
If you come upon something like this write me here. Maybe I can help.

I found the link [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-8528) very useful. Thanks.